# Java execute webpage

Tags: java, html, cookies, jsoup, webengine

I have a problem , I'm trying to do an app that connect a webpage and login , I have find jsoup and webenginr , the problem that after the login a JavaScript redirect me in another page , how can login in page and use JavaScript for redirect me in java ?
Jsoup I try but it get out the problem that JavaScript aren't enable , and webengine I must use it less GUI , how can I do ?

Comment: You can do a network trace in your browser to find out which url the javascript is redirecting you to. Then fire that url manually.

Comment: Or use tools which support JavaScript, possibly Selenium webdriver.